# How can i access to JinternlFrme in one Jframe through other Jframes?

Tags: swing, jframe, netbeans-6.9, jinternalframe

I'm working with Netbeans and I have two `JFrame`s in same package:`F1` and `F2`.

`F1` consists of two `JInternalFrame`s that are named `in1` and `in2`.

`F2` consists of a `Jbutton` named `but`.

Now, how can I show `in1` (InternalJframe in F1), when I press `but`(jbutton in F2)?
I mean how can I access `in1` that is in `F1` through `F2`?

Answer (score 0):

First you create F1:

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    F1 myF1 = new F1();
    F2 myF2 = new F2( myF1 );
    ...
    ...
}
```

You can create F2 with argument of F1:

```
public class F2 extends JFrame
{
    private F1 f1Frame;
    private JButton but;
    public F2( F1 _fromF1 )
    {
         f1Frame = _fromF1;
         but = new JButton("button");
         ...
         ...
         but.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
             {
                 f1Frame.makein1Visible();
             }
         } );
         ....
         ...
    }
}
```

In F1 class implement a function which makes visible in1:

```
public void makein1Visible()
{
    in1.setVisible( true );
}
```